# Is there a free software to split a PNG image into some smaller images?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a large image. It will be better if I can split it into m columns by n rows of smaller images.

Is there a free software to split a PNG  image into some smaller images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ImageMagick is great for doing things like this from command-line if you need to write batch scripts for image processing:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

Comment: what is the switch to slice an image into m by n smaller images?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

Answer (score 3):

The GIMP or Paint.NET are the common options

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I prefer to use the programmable one, i.e., ImageMagick rather than the WYSIWYG.