# Split image into 16x16px or 32x32px sections then save them individually?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, tiles

I want to split up the terrain.png image from Minecraft to use in some projects.  Is there a quicker way to split the image than selecting each 16x16px section and copy-pasting the sections into new files?

Here is an example:

[image: Example image]

Comment: This might not be 100% on-topic, but are you allowed to use the minecraft textures for just any project?

Comment: That is a good point. Hopefully the projects referred to are personal projects, because you can't use these images in a commercial project.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Slice Tool like this:

1. Drag out a slice that encompasses the entire image. You want a "slice", in other words, that is the entire image.
2. Right-click (Ctl-click with 1-button mouse on a Mac) and choose "Divide Slice" from the context menu. Select your slice sizes and click OK. (Note: you might consider choosing *how many* slices, rather than what size. It might make things a bit easier when it comes to reassembling the slices.)
3. Choose "Save for Web&Devices",  set whatever parameters will work best for your application, choose a directory in which to save the slices and hit Save. The save creates a folder called "images" and puts all of your slices in there, each with the original filename plus a numeric suffix.

You're done.

[Late edit:] I had one of those forehead-smacking moments. On step 3, choose "Save As Type: HTML and images" to have Photoshop output the slices and a handy HTML Table that puts everything where it should be. One of the few cases where tables are somewhat useful in web design.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite a duplicate of this other question (although you don't state it in the question, your tags imply that you want to do this in Photoshop) but I can give the exact same answer: [Is there a free software to split a PNG image into some smaller images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/is-there-a-free-software-to-split-a-png-image-into-some-smaller-images)

---

ImageMagick is great for doing things like this from command-line if you need to write batch scripts for image processing:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile